# How to change syntax for a specific folder in Sublime Text 3

Tags: javascript, sublime-text-2, syntax-highlighting, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I write JS projects in ES5 and ES6. I installed [Babel-Sublime](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime) for highlighting Babel supported code. Now, I open a .js file written in ES6, goto "View -> syntax -> Open all with current extension as : Javascript (Babel)", but this causes my ES5 code to also switch to Javascript (Babel). Basically,the JavaScript (Babel).sublime-settings file is updated in the User folder with the extension mapping and the change is applied globally to all my projects. So, is there a way to specify "syntax to extension" mapping per folder or per project basis

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you can specify project-level settings using `your_project_name.sublime-project` file. Take a look at **Project** menu and the [sublime documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html#the-sublime-project-format).

Though, sublime doesn't support syntax settings in the `.sublime-project` files. So you have to use [Sublime Project Specific Syntax](https://github.com/reywood/sublime-project-specific-syntax) package. This works for me with Sublime Text 3. Pay attention to use the `Project Specific Syntax > Copy syntax setting to clipboard` menu item.

For `Babel-Sublime` syntax highlighting following should work:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
  "syntax_override": {
    "\\.js$": ["Babel", "JavaScript (Babel)"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. That package worked perfectly. I still wish there would be a folder level syntax_override option, to avoid creating sublime-projects, which when committed to shared repos may not be useful to everyone

Comment: @tapsboy years too late, but in case anyone else comes across this, you can store the project file (.sublime-project) outside the project folder/s, ie. outside the repo, if that's useful. I do that for the reason you identified.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how ChatGPT can ever replace this amazing community